# Get to know tomcat is running on which port before the request is made

Tags: java, tomcat7, servletcontextlistener

I have a simple class "StarterClass" which implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener. It is overridden method of the ServletContextListener class i.e. contextInitialized(), I would like to know which port Tomcat is running on. The main aim here is to find something unique for this tomcat which I think is the port as there can be more tomcats running on one machine but with different port

I am sorry if this question is already answered but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does identifying the Tomcat you're running on helps your application? I'm sure whatever you're trying to do, there's probably a much better way.

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your answer, I have to make a unique name for this tomcat ans send it to other module using IPC, So I planning to make a name using MAC id and tomcat port. What basically happens in the other module is that it keeps track of this tomcat instance so that it can sens message to this tomcat as to when it should stop taking requests.

Comment: I suggest configuring the unique id in your *web.xml* and making it available throughout the application as a global servlet context attribute. Since, the identifier would hardly change configuring it makes more sense as opposed to calculating it every time.

Comment: Thanks again, but that may not be a suitable here because there is a same copy of the war that can be deployed in same machine or different machine, if I put in web.xml, they will all send same unique-id which is a problem. This id has to be unique for each war that can be deployed on same or different machine hence I decided to use mac id and port.

Comment: By configuring, I meant you would be setting up different identifiers for different installations as a one-time deployment activity (doesn't matter on the same machine or not).

Comment: Thanks Ravi, the war is given to our customers who may simply make a copy of this war and bring it on same machine but different tomcat or different machine. So every time making an entry to web.xml is not a possible scenario here.